# Recode Variable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I got a question on recoding variables in shiny. I try to explain my issue on the minimal example below. I have a dataset. Due to the selection on the „selectInput“ I can Subset my data. This works very fine.

```
data <- reactive(fileInput(inputId = "data", label = "Data Input“))

selectInput(inputId = "select", label = "Subset", 
                     c("A" = "a", 
                       "B" = "b"))

sub.dat  <- reactive(
if (input$select == "a") {subset(data(), select c(v1:v21))} 
else if  (input$select == "b") {subset(data(), select = c(v22:v40))} 
else {})
```

Now I need to recode my variables in the subsets. I tried it this way:

```
sub.dat <- reactive(
if (input$select == "a") 
 {
df <- subset(data(), select = c(v1:v21)) 
for (i in 1:21) {
df[[paste0("v", i)]] <- recode(df[[paste0("v", i)]], "1"="0", "2"="1", "3"="2", "4"="3", "NA"="NA")
} 
 df
}
)
```

**how can I Subset in relation to input$select AND recode inside one reactive expression?**

But it won’t work. Anybody an idea how to manage this? Maybe in an elegant way with mutate?

Thanks a lot
derlu

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you are looking for, please?

Comment: Cant provide the data due to license agreements. I’m looking for a possibility to Subset the data and directly recode the variables.

Comment: Input are numerical values, output also should be numerical values

Comment: Input range 1 to 4. output should be range 0 to 3

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 dat <- sample(1:4, 20, replace = T)
 dat %>% recode(`2` = 1L, `4` = 3L)
```

> [1] 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 1

`dat`

> [1] 3 3 2 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 1 4 3 2 1 3 2 3 2 2

You can combine this with your select to make this more tidy like this:

```
df <- data() %>% filter(v:1 %in% input$select) %>% recode(`1` = 0L,`2` = 1L, `3` = 2L,`4` = 3L)
```

I did not run that line so you may need to tweak the filter. you will need to identify the correct observation and that input$select is in the right format.

Comment: My problem is, that there is a problem recoding inside the reactive dataset. Normally the recode function works, also as loop. But not inside  ‘reactive()‘. I think my exact question is: how can I Subset in relation to input$select AND recode inside one reactive expression?

Comment: I added more to my answer to do both. Another option to limit the reactivity is to use isolate() on areas you may not want to invalidate a reactive variable.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: Still doesn’t work. Says: cannot recode logical values. If i replicate the code as a normal R script, it works. But not inside a shin environment in a reactive variable

Comment: Can you send me something reproducible? I am not able to recreate your issue. I'd be happy to continue to help, I just need something to recreate it with.